# How to Programmatically Close Google Workspace Add-in and Refresh Inbox on Action Completion?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm developing a Google Workspace Add-in that prompts users with 'Yes' and 'No' options. I'm facing two challenges:

On 'Yes' Selection: I need the add-in to close, return the user to their inbox, and refresh it to reflect changes (like an email being deleted). I've tried using CardService.newNavigation().popToRoot(), but it doesn't help producing the result I am looking for.

On 'No' Selection: The add-in should close, leaving the user on the current email without a refresh. The same method as above doesn't achieve this either.

Is there a way to programmatically close the Google Workspace Add-in and trigger an inbox refresh upon completing an action within the add-in?

Thanks